# Failing to get Debian 7 i836 updates

Tags: debian, apt-get

I was trying to install teamviewer on Debian 7.

But when I was doing:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i836 ; apt-get update
```

I was getting the following Error :

> > W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/Release  Unable to
> >     find expected entry 'main/binary-i836/Packages' in Release file (Wrong
> >     sources.list entry or malformed file)
> >
> > W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/Release 
> >     Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i836/Packages' in Release
> >     file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/Release  Unable to
>   find expected entry 'main/binary-i836/Packages' in Release file (Wrong
>   sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

and my /etc/apt/source.list is as follows:

> deb [arch=i836,amd64] http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main
>   deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main
>
> deb [arch=i836,amd64] http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates
>   main deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main
>
> deb [arch=i836,amd64] http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
>   deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

Any ideas I don't get the x86 updates as I should?

(At last I just installed ia32 lib and remove i836 architecure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's i386, not i836. :-)

`dpkg --add-architecture i386 ; apt-get update`

Comment: I cant believe that i even posted something like that sry

Comment: Of course that was the mistake...( i am drunk all day :D)

Comment: i should remove that stupid question